# Regex to remove newlines not followed by specific string

Tags: regex, shell, perl, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I have a delimited data file with user entry that I need to clean up.  Specifically:

1. There are newlines embedded in free text fields that I want to remove
2. The number of columns can change from one row to the next
3. The first field of each row **SHOULD ALWAYS** start with the pattern `"INC\d{12}"` (the double quotes are part of the pattern).
4. Each `\n` should be replaced by a single space if it is not immediately followed by the pattern `"INC\d{12}"`
5. I am currently using Perl (preferred) in cygwin, but awk or sed answers are acceptable as well.

Here is some mock input data (I saved my to a file named `test_input_so.txt`):

```
"INC000111111111", "field2", "field3"

"INC000222222222", "field2", "field3","INC000123456789 blahblah"



"INC000444444444", "fie"""ld2", "field3"
"INC000123

456789", "field2", "field3",
"INC000333333333", "INC000123456789", "field3""
"INC000555555555", "field2", "fiel
d3","field4"
```

Here is the desired output for the above data:

```
"INC000111111111", "field2", "field3"    
"INC000222222222", "field2", "field3","INC000123456789 blahblah"
"INC000444444444", "fie"""ld2", "field3"
"INC000123456789", "field2", "field3",
"INC000333333333", "INC000123456789", "field3""
"INC000555555555", "field2", "field3","field4"
```

I have tried several combinations of negative lookaheads/behinds, but I am not sure why it is not working.

Here is one example:

```
perl -pe 's/\n(?!"INC\d{12})/ /g;' test_input_so.txt
```

It strips all `\n`, but incorrectly removes the `\n` followed by "INC123456789012" which **should** have been left in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`perl -pe ...` works with one line a time, so a multi-line regular expression won't do you any good.

The [`-0`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlrun#-0[octal/hexadecimal]) switch to Perl can change your input record separator (what Perl's notion of a line is) and allow you to operate on the entire input as a single string.

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\n(?!"INC\d{12})/ /g;' test_input_so.txt
```

Comment: it removes ````INC000123456789```` from the expected output, but it also contradicts OP's requirement ````"INC\d{12}"````

Comment: could you please review my answer and suggest improvements.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have some stray quotes that you need to fix so your data can be valid CSV:

- line 7: `"fie"""ld2"` must be `"fie""ld2"`
- line 11: ends with 2 double quotes

Second, don't put a space after the comma between fields: not `a, b` but `a,b`

Once you repair those things, you can use the [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) module:

What I think you really want to do is **remove newlines that are *inside* quoted fields**. The structure of this code is taken from the Text::CSV perldoc.

```
perl -MData::Dump=dd -E '
    use Text::CSV;
    my $csv = Text::CSV->new ({ binary => 1, always_quote => 1 })
                   or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();

    my $file = shift @ARGV;
    open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", $file or die;
    while ( my $row = $csv->getline( $fh ) ) {
        my @row = map {s/\n//g; $_} @$row;
        $csv->combine(@row);
        my $line = $csv->string();
        say $line if $line ne q{""};
    }
    $csv->eof or $csv->error_diag();
    close $fh;
' test_input_so.txt
```

```
"INC000111111111","field2","field3"
"INC000222222222","field2","field3","INC000123456789 blahblah"
"INC000444444444","fie""ld2","field3"
"INC000123456789","field2","field3",""
"INC000333333333","INC000123456789","field3"
"INC000555555555","field2","field3","field4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Perl

```
$  perl -0777 -ne ' while( /(^"INC00.+?)(\n"INC.*|\Z)/msg ) { $x=$1;$_=$2; $x=~s/\n//g; print "$x\n" } ' test_input_so.txt
"INC000111111111", "field2", "field3"
"INC000222222222", "field2", "field3","INC000123456789 blahblah"
"INC000444444444", "fie"""ld2", "field3"
"INC000123456789", "field2", "field3",
"INC000333333333", "INC000123456789", "field3""
"INC000555555555", "field2", "field3","field4"
$
```

Input:

```
$ cat test_input_so.txt
"INC000111111111", "field2", "field3"

"INC000222222222", "field2", "field3","INC000123456789 blahblah"



"INC000444444444", "fie"""ld2", "field3"
"INC000123

456789", "field2", "field3",
"INC000333333333", "INC000123456789", "field3""
"INC000555555555", "field2", "fiel
d3","field4"

$
```